# Getting and displaying IMDB poster on private webserver with PHP/JS/JQUERY(/PY?)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, imdb, imdbpy

I know this question has been asked. But the latest one I found was over 3 years ago.

I have an imdb movie id and I want to get the poster and display it in the results of a query. (e.g. user searches a query through php/html (ive got that sorted so far) and a list of movies comes up. each movie has an imdb movie id. I want to display the poster image next to/with the movie name in the query).

I know that on the imdb page the img I want has id=poster(or something similar) in the img tag. do i need to search the webpage for something with id=poster then copy the link somehow? how?

I hope someone can help. I've tried all day using almost everything I can find but i cant get to work. a common fix in some i found was imdbapi.com. but thats shut down and become omdbapi.com (which if i want their poster api, I will need to donate.)

Doesn't Plex use something similar to get their pictures? (I'm not sure though.)

If i use PHP i might overload the server because it'll be taking all the images and sending them to the user. So if i used a Jquery/JS method that would place majority of the 'strain' on the user's device by getting them to access the urls themselves. instead of being handed the images over the Internet. I think.

Efficient or not. This is just a prototype webpage.

Comment: If the images are online you can use basically any language to scrape the images. Are you thinking of doing this in real time as a query is made on your webapp?

Comment: yes. idealy. i make the query from a series of inputs in a form. then when the query is put through it currently displays the movie's name. but i want it to also display the poster for the movie and then the name underneath. i just dont know how to get the link for the image and display it in the query results.

Comment: There are quite literally thousands of ways to do this across different languages and platforms. One way you could do this however is to download the image to your server on request and keep the copy there for a period of time (a day, a month, a year). This would mean you'd only have to download it once and for all users past the first request it would be quicker. But this question is highly opinion based, and therefore off topic. I think it would be best if you looked at how you would like to do this and asked about that method rather than asking how you should do this.